# Multi input & output CNN

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I have the following problem:

```
Input: a set of 6 images
Output: a probability for each image determining whether the image is the correct one out of the 6 images
```

I know how to create a CNN with keras, but not how to have multiple images as an input.
How would one solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to use a pre-trained model (VGG16 etc.) and extract out the vectors from some intermediate layer, then concat 6 vectors together then feed it into a neural network (or some other classification model) and train it as a multiclass classification task.

You can also use an Autoencoder and take the anomaly detection approach.